# Over heating subaru outback

Tags: overheating

My Subaru outback as engine problems. Engine light comes on the vehicle over heats. I have replaced the  engine  on the vehicle  2x. Both times the engine over heated.
This is a 2011 outback 2.5L engine.
Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?
New thermostat was installed.

Comment: Please close this question: I added the detail to the earlier question.